# ¿Cómo puedo insertar delay en Python?

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo insertar una espera en una implementación python tradicional con este esquema:

```
print "hacer algo"
#esperar
print "hacer algo extra"
```

Comment: Nicolas, revisa por favor lo definido en el [help], para realizar una pregunta [ask], puedes modificar tu pregunta y puede ser reabierta!, saludos..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En una pregunta frecuente que me toca resolver, por este motivo la dejo aquí junto a un par de propuestas.

```
import time
time.sleep(15) # espera en segundos
```

Algo así para validar

```
import time

print "mensaje inicial antes de la espera"
time.sleep(15) # espera en segundos
print "mensaje luego de la espera"
```

o algo normal es hacer algo cada cierto tiempo, un ejemplo podría ser.

```
while True:
    print("imprimir mensaje cada 5 segundos")
    time.sleep(5) # espera en segundos
```